# Finding a simpler Python RegEx for a string that contains each character at least once

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a small project and have need for Regular Expressions that accept strings that contain each character in a given alphabet *at least once*.

So for the alphabet `{J, K, L}` I would need a RegEx that accepts strings containing `J` one or more times AND `K` one or more times, AND `L` one or more times, in any order, with any amount of duplicate characters before, after, or in-between.

I'm pretty inexperienced with RegEx and so have trouble finding "lateral thinking" solutions to many problems. My first approach to this was therefore pretty brute-force: I took each possible "base" string, for example,

`JKL, JLK, KJL, KLJ, LKJ, LJK`

and allow for any string  that could be built up from one of those starting points. However the resulting regular expression* (despite working) ends up being  very long and containing a lot of redundancy. Not to mention this approach becomes completely untenable once the alphabet has more than a handful of characters.

I spent a few hours trying to find a more elegant approach, but I have yet to find one that still accepts every possible string. Is there a method or technique I could be using to get this done in a way that's more elegant and scalable (to larger alphabets)?

*For reference, my regular expression for the listed example:

```
((J|K|L)*J(J|K|L)*K(J|K|L)*L(J|K|L)*)|
((J|K|L)*J(J|K|L)*L(J|K|L)*K(J|K|L)*)|
((J|K|L)*K(J|K|L)*J(J|K|L)*L(J|K|L)*)|
((J|K|L)*K(J|K|L)*L(J|K|L)*J(J|K|L)*)|
((J|K|L)*L(J|K|L)*J(J|K|L)*K(J|K|L)*)|
((J|K|L)*L(J|K|L)*K(J|K|L)*J(J|K|L)*)
```

Comment: can you post the examples of invalid inputs?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest for the listed example, any string that doesn't have at least one J, K, and L. So "JK", "KLLKK", and "JJLLLJL" would all get rejected.

Comment: The lookahead regex answer will probably be slower than looping with a string find function for each array character. They both do the same thing (i.e. start from the string beginning), however the regex has some overhead states ( like assertion groups and negated classes ) that would make it slower.

Comment: @sln thanks for the tip. This project is primarily for experimenting with RegEx, but I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: If you just want to mess around with regex and looking for a different than assertions approach, use the new _regex_ module and try this on it `(?:.*?(?:((?(1)(?!))j)|((?(2)(?!))k)|((?(3)(?!))l))){3}` Because assertions aren't really experimenting are they? Try and [benchmark](http://www.regexformat.com) experiments, you may be surprised at what you find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typical use-case for a lookahead. You can simply use `^(?=[^J]*J)(?=[^K]*K)(?=[^L]*L)` to check all your conditions. If your string also must contain only these characters, you can append `[JKL]+$` to it.

Comment: Perfect. I had seen look ahead before, but it wasn't in my "mental toolbox" when thinking through problems.

Answer (score 3):

If using regex is not a requirement you could also check for the characters individually:

```
text = ...
alphabet = 'JKL'
assert all([character in text for character in alphabet])
```

Or if you do not want to allow characters that are not in the alphabet:

```
assert set(alphabet) == set(text)
```